# How do you pass a cell value into the filter criteria of another row using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function:

```
Sub GreaterI()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AA$2006").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">1.25" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Which when fired filters the 9th column to show only values greater than 1.25.

Instead of 1.25 being hard-coded, I want the function to look at cell B1 for that value.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
Sub GreaterI()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AA$2006").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">" + Range("B1").Value _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Then just save the value in B1 into a variable and then pass that into the criteria1. If you want a function you would need to pass a sheet name function GreaterI(sh as worksheet).

Comment: change `+` to `&`. Also, if you the value in `B1` is on a different sheet, you need to qualify the sheet: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman As simple as that! Thank you very much, not quite sure how to flag your answer as the correct one? but thank you!

Comment: no worries on correct answer. it was just a syntax mistake